# Try catch on v if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, try-catch

I have a `v-if` that shows an error message in HTML

```
    <div id="error" v-if="showError">Error User or Password</div>

  data() {
    return {
      showError: false,
};}
```

if I set in data `showError: true` it appears.

But when I call it in inside my catch:

```
  catch (error) {
    alert('Usuário ou senha inválidos')

  }
```

the `alert` works fine but if I send

```
showError = true
```

or

```
showError: true;
```

do not appears the error message in HTML(`v-if`)

how do i do that?

Comment: Worked thanks!!! im trying now to do a setTimeout to make false the showError, do you know how? i tried: setTimeout(this.showError = false,10000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the member to `true` and then wait for a while before you set it to `false`. Like this:

```
this.showError = true;
setTimeout(() => {
    this.showError = false;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes thanks for pointing it out, I have edited my answer accordingly.